# netplan apply does not change the IP address

Tags: networking, server, netplan

ok, my file is located at /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
I changed the IP address as a static IP address as following:

```
network:
  version: 2 

  renderer: netwokrd

  ethernets:

    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: [10.0.2.100/24]
    gateway4: 10.0.2.1
    nameservers:
       addresses: [10.0.2.100]
```

Then, I typed sudo netplan apply, and there was not any error message.
BUT, when I typed ifconfig, it still remail past IP address on enp0s3.
Do you guys know why this happen?

Comment: maybe unrelated, but in your example file you have a typo: netwokrd instead of networkd

Answer (score 10):

Netplan is fussy about how .yaml files are formatted. Don't try to "pretty-fy" them.

Is `50-cloud-init.yaml` the only .yaml file in `/etc/netplan`?

So edit your .yaml file to look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2 
  renderer: networkd                   # note the correct spelling
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:                            # identify the proper interface
      addresses: [10.0.2.100/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.2.100]        # this is probably the wrong address
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]  # use something like this instead
```

then do:

```
sudo netplan generate          # generate the config files
sudo netplan apply             # apply the new configuration
reboot                         # reboot the computer
```

and recheck your `ifconfig` output.

**Note**: if it was me, I'd let NetworkManager manage this interface, and set the static address information into the "Wired Connection" profile.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

then do:

```
sudo netplan generate          # generate the config files
sudo netplan apply             # apply the new configuration
reboot                         # reboot the computer
```

Comment: since the netplan config is in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml it is likely this is a cloud image which has no NetworkManager installed.

Comment: Why do you must reboot? Is there any other way?

Comment: @Nimitack technically, the `sudo netplan -debug generate` and `sudo netplan apply` commands should do it, but I've seen cases where it didn't, and a reboot will actually start with the netplan configuration you've set, and you can confirm that it's working as expected.

Comment: I see this issue on vmware machine and on virtual box.. when I install ubuntu 18.04... I really need this to NOT reboot.. I couldn't find anything about this on the web.. this is pretty basic stuff, static IP. I don't understand why to reset it.. it's not hardware or so..., Linux is all about NOT rebooting right?

Comment: @Nimitack I'm confused. I indicated that a reboot is not mandatory, however, it MAY be required if the `sudo netplan apply` doesn't do it.

Comment: I tried many times.. could not get static IP without reboot. I think that this bug need to be in high priority. 18.04 is LTS.

Comment: @Nimitack Please start a new question for your problem, and include your .yaml file, then ping me at "@heynnema"

Comment: @heynnema https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103322/ubuntu-18-04-static-ip-with-netplan-require-reboot

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have experienced the same issue working with ubuntu 18.04 .The config file aplies the changes good for dhcp interfaces and for static ip´s I had to do first as a root (or whith sudo if not) this steps

1. ip link set enp0s(x) down
2. ip addr add x.x.x.x/x.x.x.x dev enp0s(x).
3. ip link set enp0s(x) up
4. and then configure the same interface with same values at  /etc/netplan/*.yaml

I think the steps are in this order but I´m not sure, but of course you must up and down the interface and config the interface with both ip addr and the netplan config file. After some attemps that worked for me and after reboot everything continues working, I didn´t lose any config value

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set a static IP in Ubuntu 18.04 server and, even with perfectly correct yaml in /etc/netplan and multiple tries using --debug and netplan generate and netplan apply, etc., just wouldn't take - stuck using DHCP.

Decided to compare the yaml in /etc/netplan and the network file in /etc/systemd/network - network file stuck with DHCP and not being updated (is it supposed to update?).

Regardless, deleted the network file, ran netplan generate / netplan apply and voila working now even after a reboot. And no network file generated in /etc/systemd/network. Go figure.