# Ubuntu 18.04 Static IP with NetPlan require reboot

Tags: networking, 18.04

I need to provide OVA with static IP.

I'm using clean Ubuntu 18.04 image and running (testing) on virtual box and vmware.

When I configure the IP address in the yaml file, and running the command:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Nothing changes.

Only when I reboot the machine, the IP address changes.

This is what inside my yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2 
  renderer:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.2.100/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Typically, Linux does not require rebooting.
Please help me.

@heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Can you help me?

Comment: FYI: change `rederer:` to `renderer: networkd`.

Comment: FYI #2: use `sudo netplan -debug generate` before `sudo netplan apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with my machine.
It was an issue with the `renderer`, it is documented that Ubuntu server should come with `networkd` but in my machine (Ubuntu Server 18.04) the network manager that installed is `network-manager` so I changed the `renderer` to `NetworkManager` and it started to work again.

You can check if `network-manager` is installed by `sudo service network-manager status`.

I still don't know why `network-manager` is installed instead of `networkd` but at least it is working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

In your .yaml file, you're missing the renderer definition. It should say:

```
renderer: networkd
```

See if the `ip` command will help...

**Bring interfaces up or down**

Previously users were used to using the ifconfig command. Users should now familiarize themselves with the more powerful `ip` command. Manually modifying network devices is now accomplished via the `ip` command.

As an example to bring up an interface and bring it back down:

```
ip link set enp0s3 up
ip link set enp0s3 down
```

See "man ip" for more information on how to manipulate the state of routing, network devices, interfaces and tunnels.

source: https://netplan.io/faq

Comment: The interface goes to down/up, but IP doesn’t change.

Comment: You might look at `ip address { add | change | replace } IFADDR dev IFNAME`, and other `ip address` commands.

Comment: Can someone dumb down how to setup this public IP. I just have a 50-cloud-init.yaml in my /etc/netplan. It just has network:
    `ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2`

Comment: @Sam-T please start a new question and I'll be glad to assist. Post the entire content of your .yaml in your question. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema Here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196582/setup-public-ip-on-ubuntu-18-04-on-vm-player

Answer (score 0):

Check that your yaml file in the /etc/netplan/ directory has the highest number preceding the rest of the filename. The Highest number is processed last, and overrides any previous config. Eg. 50-cloud-config.yaml will be processed first, followed by 60-my-new-config.yaml. If 60-my-new-config.yaml reconfigures a device that was listed in the earlier file, then the later config will be applied.

Note too, that if you configured a device in an earlier file, and don't reconfigure it in the later file, then the original device will still be present. This could cause a conflict with your attempt to assign a static IP (eg. device enp0s3 is referenced in a bridge or bond previously, and then the new config cannot be applied).

To check for errors, run the generate command with "--debug" (two dashes not one, as in the comments):

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

If there is a problem with the script, it will be listed for you to correct. Otherwise, running apply will not make anything change (although your script looks fine - the default renderer is "networkd" if nothing else is specified).

Then apply using the try command, to roll back if there is an error:

```
sudo netplan --debug try
```

Check results with the networkctl and/or ip command to see what you got.

```
sudo networkctl status enp0s3
sudo ip address show enp0s3
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196582/setup-public-ip-ubuntu-18-04-on-vm-player