# netplan apply does not change interface name while reboot does

Tags: netplan

This is not duplicate of
[Ubuntu 18.04 Static IP with NetPlan require reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103322/ubuntu-18-04-static-ip-with-netplan-require-reboot)
I tried with both renderers with no lack. Changes are applied only after reboot. I tried ifup/ifdown/netplan apply. Nothing works.
Fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on physical hardware.
network-manager was not installed by default. I installed to test both renderers.
I changed settings and used networkd as renderer. Changed again and used NetworkManager as renderer. After reboot latest changes are applied.
Server has 2 raid controllers and it takes looong to reboot.
According to documentation reboot is not needed.
Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ifconfig <old name> down` then `sudo ip link set <old name> name <new name>` then `sudo ifconfig <new name> up`?  If that works, then you make the change to your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` to match.  See:  https://serverfault.com/questions/910406/persistently-rename-a-linux-network-interface-without-udev-reboot

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Did you manually install NetworkManager? Is your problem a interface name problem as the title suggests, or a netplan reboot problem, as the body suggests? Some netplan changes DO require a reboot.

Comment: This is server. If I specified renderer: NetworkManager, after netplan apply I got error NetworkManager service not found. I checked, it was not installed by default (I installed minimal server). I installed network-manager (sudo apt install network-manager) and after it, I could use both renderers.
To test further, I created 2 config files in netplan folder. One uses networkd as renderer and second uses NetworkManager. I changed names of adapters in both config files. netplan apply did not affect it. After reboot, both changes are in effect.

Comment: @Terrance This works. I am configuring different things and setting 4 NICS. If I have to do it in two different ways (one which works immediately and another after reboot), I am going to mess. I like netplan idea of yaml file. I can see all settings at once.

Comment: My next step was to add bridge. I installed bridge-utils, added bridge to netplan config, run netplan apply and changes were visible immediately????
Bridge state was DOWN. I restarted server and got errors when bringing network up