# Setup Public IP on Ubuntu 18.04 (on VM Player)

Tags: networking, 18.04, vmware, ip, netplan

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Server guest, on Win10 Pro Host, on VM Player 15.5, I am in my home network.
Need to setup public IP, went thru several threads etc - tried this:
[How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

I had `50-cloud-init.yaml`, instead of editing this file, created a new file `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` (assuming this works ??)  with suggested net plan:
`network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.222/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]`

`sudo netplan apply`

`ip a`

3: flannel.1:  mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether ea:3b:a8:80:ec:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
**4: docker0**: `<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:e6:74:3b:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Per instructions I should have gotten **enp0s3** for next steps - I did not get that - instead this `docker0`.  Here is where I am stuck

**Update 1**
**I have 3 files in etc/netplan**
01-netcfg.yaml (new file I added - as above)
50-cloud-init.yaml  (original file)
50-cloud-init.yaml.save

`50-cloud-init.yaml`
`network:
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2`

`sudo netplan --debug apply`

** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.820: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.823: starting new processing pass
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.824: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.825: starting new processing pass
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.826: enp0s3: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.826: Configuration is valid
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.827: ens33: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.827: Configuration is valid
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.827: Generating output files..
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.828: NetworkManager: definition enp0s3 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:121337): DEBUG: 02:01:42.828: NetworkManager: definition ens33 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp0s3 not found in {}
DEBUG:ens33 not found in {'enp0s3': {'dhcp4': False, 'addresses': ['192.168.1.222/24'], 'gateway4': '192.168.1.1', 'nameservers': {'addresses': ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']}}}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.222/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device ens33 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: flannel.1
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: docker0
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for ens33
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for flannel.1
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0

**Update 2**
`sudo lshw -C network`
  ***-network***
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:93:92:0c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 
 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.37.128 latency=0 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
  **-network:0**
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:e6:74:3b:7b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  ***-network:1**
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: flannel.1
       serial: ea:3b:a8:80:ec:63
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vxlan driverversion=0.1 ip=10.1.91.0 link=yes multicast=yes

**Update 3**
$ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.872: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.873: starting new processing pass
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.873: ens33: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.874: Configuration is valid
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.874: Generating output files..
** (generate:52920): DEBUG: 22:48:00.875: NetworkManager: definition ens33 is not for us (backend 1)

Comment: Are there other .yaml files in /etc/netplan? If so, show them all to me. Always do a `sudo netplan --debug generate` before your `sudo netplan apply`, otherwise you risk taking down a server if the `generate` fails. It gives you time to fix the error. I don't understand your items 3 and 4. And why is the MTU 1450? 1500 in docker?

Comment: update the main post

Comment: Show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema  - added above

Comment: The only real difference between my .yaml and the 50-cloud-init.yaml is that mine uses the static IP that you were trying to set, instead of dhcp. As long as it was a valid unused IP, it should have been transparent.