# Set multiple wifi access points in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, wireless-access-point

I am trying to configure the network in Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to set up several wifi access points under the same interface.

I am using the following configuration right now:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            addresses: [x.y.z.w/24]
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
      wlan0:
        dhcp4: false
        gateway4: x.y.z.w
        addresses: [x.y.z.w/24]
        access-points:
          "SSID":
            password: "pass"
```

But only one access point can be specified. Is it possible to set up a list of wifi networks with corresponding credentials?

Answer (score 3):

May be you already found answer for this, still posting, make sure that both HotSpots are 2.4GHz.
Just append bold line to `/etc/netplan/50-something.yaml` fileL

```
wifis:
      wlan0:
        dhcp4: false
        gateway4: x.y.z.w
        addresses: [x.y.z.w/24]
        access-points:
          "SSID1":
            password: "pass1"
          "SSID2":
            password: "pass2"
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample code is as follow.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.
# Changes to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable
# cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the
# following: network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            addresses: [x.y.z.w/24]
            optional: true
    version: 2        
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "first-network-ssid":
                    password: 'first-network-password'
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "second-network-ssid":
                    password: 'second-network-password'
            dhcp4: true
```

The

> first-network-ssid

should be replace with your first network ssid, then the

> first-network-password

should be replace with your first network password, so with the

> second-network-ssid

> second-network-password

If another wifi need to added, add a wlan config as the children node to  wifis.

The header must be **wlan0**.

Finally [update netplan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083497/1151021).

To [select the wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458963/412884), first show the wifi list

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 list_networks
```

it will show you the network_id and network_ssid,
then select by network_id.

```
 sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 select_network network_id
```